# Como verificar o uso de memória no Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Estou há pouco tempo desenvolvendo um projeto asp.net mvc 5.

Quando eu chamo uma view (uma página), a memória RAM esgota pra 0MB. Aí o PC ferra.

Quando a memória RAM  volta para normal, ele mostra página view.

Alguém pode me dizer se um Visual Studio existe essa ferramenta para detectar o consumo de memória, ver quem faz ele esgotar memória.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O Visual Studio tem uma janela específica para diagnósticos chamada `Diagnostic Tools`. Que entre outras funções de monitoramento, mostra a quantidade de memória utilizada pela aplicação.

Sempre que você executa seu projeto pressionando `F5`, ela deve aparecer automaticamente.

Você também pode fazê-la surgir acessando `Debug > Windows > Show Diagnostic Tools` ou pressionando `Ctrl + Alt + F2`